# Dirac Delta as continuum limit

Tags: vector-spaces, dirac-delta

Suppose function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is approximated as shown in the  figure.

[image]

$$|f\rangle \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
f_1\\
f_2\\
\vdots\\
f_N
\end{pmatrix}$$
The derivative defined as
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
In this case,
$$\left.\frac{df}{dx}\right|_{i^\text{th} \text{bin}}=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f_{i+1}-f_i}{1/N}=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}N(f_{i+1}-f_i)$$

So I can write the derivative operator as a matrix like

$$D=N\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0& \cdots \\
0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots \\
\vdots&0&-1&\cdots 
\end{pmatrix}_{(N-1)\times (N-1)}$$

Now it is said, in the problem that I'm working on, that as $N\rightarrow \infty$ the operator $D$ becomes an operator $\mathcal{D}$ with the property
$$\int \mathcal{D}(x,x')f(x')dx'=\frac{df}{dx}$$

I don't understand, How does one show this? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yeah, You are right, I was just a typo. Can you help me proving this?

Comment: Where are you stuck, and how rigorous does this need to be? I'd start by asking what the  matrix equivalent of a delta function looks like, and how to prove that.

Comment: There was a mistake that  I have corrected. It's due to symbol that I was using, I have corrected it now

Comment: I'm asking How do I go about showing  this?